# Winsock working with different versions

Tags: delphi, winapi, winsock2

I wrote a packet interceptor to dump information from send/recv function from winsock and as far as i know, both function are located in ws2_32.dll; The hook is done by writing a jmp to a function that logs the information i need and then calls the original function, the hook itself works just fine.

The really weird part is that i started noticing that i was unable to log any RECV call, while SEND calls were being intercepted just fine.

The function that writes the hook is the following:

```
procedure Setup;
var
  lModuleHandle : dword;
  lPlaceHolder  : dword;
begin
  lModuleHandle := LoadLibrary(MODULE_NAME);

  OriginalSend := Dword(GetProcAddress(lModuleHandle, FUNCTION_SEND));
  OriginalRecv := Dword(GetProcAddress(lModuleHandle, FUNCTION_RECV));

  VirtualProtect(Ptr(OriginalSend), 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, lPlaceHolder);
  VirtualProtect(Ptr(OriginalRecv), 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, lPlaceHolder);

  PByte(OriginalRecv)^ := $E9;
  PDword(OriginalRecv + 1)^ := Dword(@Hook_Recv) - OriginalRecv - 5;

  PByte(OriginalSend)^ := $E9;
  PDword(OriginalSend + 1)^ := Dword(@Hook_Send) - OriginalSend - 5;

  Inc(OriginalSend, 5);
  Inc(OriginalRecv, 5);
end;
```

The program i'm working with (the one being intercepted) uses winsock 2 and after some debugging i noticed that i had wsock32.dll loaded and decided to put a breakpoint on its RECV while i had another breakpoint in ws2_32.dll's SEND; Both breakpoints were hit.

This means the program is using ws2_32.dll to send and wsock32.dll to recv, does this make any sense? Is this behavior normal in any way?

It is rather easy to write the hooks in different modules but since they are supposed to be different, it makes me believe something is wrong, also, some other applications in my computer (like firefox itself) have this same behavior.

I'm adding this image to explain better the situation, looks like the program links to wsock32 and end up with some ws2_32's functions.

[image: An image to explain better the situation]

Comment: `send()` and `recv()` are not the only functions available for sending/reading data.  Try hooking `WSASend()` and `WSARecv()` as well.  you might also have to hook other functions, like `WriteFile()` and `ReadFile()`, and even GetOverlappedResult()` and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`, if overlapped I/O is being used for the socket communication.

Comment: `wsock32.dll` is for Winsock 1.x, and `ws2_32.dll` is for Winsock 2.x.  `wsock32.dll` is simply a thunk that redirects commands to `ws2_32.dll`, for backwards compatibility with legacy apps. Everything should ultimately be going through `ws2_32.dll`. But that does not necessarily guarantee that `recv()` in `wsock32.dll` maps to `recv()` in `ws2_32.dll`. What it actually does is private to `wsock32.dll`'s implementation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but if the application is using ws2_32's SEND to send the information, shouldn't it use RECV from the same module to receive the data?

Comment: @CarlosCortex: that entirely depends on how the app is linking to the DLLs in the first place. And lets not forget that DLLs can be statically or dynamically linked.  If the app were using static linking, it should be using the same DLL for both functions. Maybe it is using dynamic linking instead, where it explicitly pulls `send()` from one DLL and `recv()` from the other DLL. Who knows, it is someone else's app.  Check the app's dependencies with a PE viewer app, like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com), see where the functions are actually coming from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , read the pe and it looks like my target does not link to ws2_32.dll at all, only wsock32.dll; interesting fact is that it does link to both SEND and RECV from wsock32.dll, if i explore the program during execution i can see it references wsock32.dll but ends up with ws2_32.dll's send. This seems to happen to a lot of other functions, which is rather confusing since the program is linking explicitly to wsock32.dll only; im further confused

Comment: like I said earlier, `wsock32.dll` merely provides backwards compatibility for older apps, internally it redirects most things to `w32_32.dll` (a few things redirect to other DLLs, like `mswsock.dll`). For example, `wsock32.send()` forwards directly to `ws2_32.send()`, whereas `wsock32.recv()` calls `ws2_32.WSARecv()`, not `ws2_32.recv()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau just looked at the debugger and it looks like you are right; looking deeper at wsock32 makes it clear. Do you know of any official reference about this? Also, i believe you should formally answer so i could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wsock32.dll` is for Winsock 1.x, `ws2_32.dll` if for Winsock 2.x.  Most apps link to `ws2_32.dll`, but legacy apps (and misconfigured apps) may still link to `wsock32.dll` instead.  On modern systems, `wsock32.dll` internally redirects *most* of its functions to either `ws2_32.dll` or `mswsock.dll`.

Your target app is linking to `wsock32.dll`.  You are hooking functions in `ws2_32.dll` instead.

Internally, `wsock32.send()` maps directly to `ws2_32.send()`, which is why your `send()` hook works.  However, `wsock32.recv()` **DOES NOT** map to `ws2_32.recv()`, which is why your `recv()` hook does not work.  `wsock32.recv()` actually calls `ws2_32.WSARecv()` instead.

In WinSock 2.x, the standard BSD socket functions are still available (`send()`, `recv()`, etc), but there are also Winsock-specific extended functions available as well (`WSASend()`, `WSARecv()`, etc), and Winsock 2.x sockets can also support Overlapped I/O and I/O Completion Ports as well.  So, if you really want to hook all possible avenues of data exchange within any given app, you will likely have to hook the BSD functions, the Winsock extension functions, and the I/O functions.  But, if you are just targeting one specific app, you only have to hook the functions it actually calls, (which, in this case are `send()` and `WSARecv()`).